# Power Query: How do I add a specific List/Vector as a Column

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a simple problem. Let's assume I have the following

[image]

Now I want to add a specific vector or list for example (1,2,2,1) as an additional column and it should look like

[image]

When I add "Custom Column", how do I have to enter this list that it creates exactly this column?
It should not be a index column or a calculated column because I want to specify the values depending on another column manually. It seems like it is a very simple task, but I couldn't find any solutions yet! (I feel very stupid xD)

pls help

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let Source = #table({"Column1"},{{"A"},{"B"},{"C"},{"D"}}),
Add = {{1,2,2,1}},
part1=Table.ToColumns(Source) & Add,
part2= Table.FromColumns(part1,Table.ColumnNames(Source)&{"Column2"})
in part2
```

or perhaps, if grabbing column from another table

```
let Source = #table({"Column1"},{{"A"},{"B"},{"C"},{"D"}}),
part1=Table.ToColumns(Source) & Table.ToColumns(Table.SelectColumns(SomeOtherTable,"Column9")),
part2 = Table.FromColumns(part1,Table.ColumnNames(Source)&{"Column2"})
in part2
```

Comment: Ok nice thank you! 
is it also possible to do it in the "Add custom column"?
(I'm just curious)

Comment: You could add an index, then use the add custom column which uses the row number index to pull a value of the same index from a different table if you wanted

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy your Column1
2. Open the Enter Data / Create Table UI and paste Column1
3. Add your **specific vector** as Column2 and save the new table
4. Merge the new table into your original table using both Column1

Note that Column1 has to be a key column (unique values). If it's not, create a temporary index column and use that for merging.